# Javascript form submit open new window tab, and then redirect parent page

Tags: javascript, php, forms, redirect, popup

When I submit the form I'm trying to open a new window tab and pass the values over into the new window tab. Then I need the parent page to redirect to the next page.

The problem is the form values are not passing to the new window tab.
How could I do that with the following code I have right now?

```
<form class="form" id="promo_form" method="post">
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
<input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
<input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" maxlength="5">
<button type="submit" id="promo_form_button" class="submit">Continue</button>
</form>


$(document).ready(function($){

var form = document.getElementById("promo_form");

    function goToUrl(){
        window.open("https://site.com/new-tab", "_blank");
        window.location = "https://site.com/parent-next-page"
    }

    document.getElementById("promo_form_button").onclick = goToUrl;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why use window.open when a form can target a new tab/window itself.

**HTML:**

```
<form target="_blank" method="get" action="http://google.com" id="myForm">
    <label for="q">Search: </label><input type="text" id="q" name="q" />
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() {
    window.location.href = "http://www.jsfiddle.net";
    return false;
};
```

**Example:**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ded3/)

Comment: This one is a much better solution. +1

Comment: Probably a race condition, @ShawnGrav has the right idea to fix that.

Comment: Play directly with the target by setting `document.getElementById("myForm").target`